# Require.js : Uncaught TypeError: Object function ... has no method

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, js-amd

I'm getting an Uncaught TypeError when i refresh the page, my **js/app/main.js** file can't call the method update() on **js/app/utilities/resize.js**.

### **Error output**

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function U(n){return n&&typeof n=="object"&&!me(n)&&ne.call(n,"**wrapped**")?W(n)} has no method 'update'

I haven't managed to isolate/replicate the issue into a simplified working example unfortunately. But you can click on the js files within the folder tree below for gists.

- *index.html*
- **js /**

  - *[app.js](https://gist.github.com/camoconnell/5755383)*
  - **lib /**

    - *require.js*
    - jquery.js
    - ... etc
  - **app /**

    - *[main.js](https://gist.github.com/camoconnell/5755455)* - *Uncaught TypeError @line 566*
    - **utilities /**

      - *[resize.js](https://gist.github.com/camoconnell/5755437)*
      - *scroll.js*
      - *... etc*

### app.js

```
require.config({

    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),

    baseUrl: WP.THEME_URL+"/js",

    paths: {
        app     : "app"
        , jquery  : "lib/jquery-2.0.2.min"
        , ...
        , resize    : "app/utilities/resize" 
        , ...
    }
});

require(["app/main"],function(){});
```

The method **update()** is being called on *resize.js* from *main.js*;

### **main.js**

> define([ 'require' , 'jquery' , ... ,'resize' ], function( require , $ , ... , resize ) {
>
> ...
>
> function setup() {
>
> ```
>  resize.update(); // Uncaught TypeError happens here
> ```
>
> }
>
> $doc.ready( setup );

### **resize.js**

```
define([],function () {   

    var resizeItems = [],
        update = function () {

            for (i = 0; i < resizeItems.length; i++){
                var item = resizeItems[i];
                item.callback( App.screen.width , App.screen.height );
            }
        };

    return {
        update  : update,
        add     : function( item ) { resizeItems.push( item ); }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

---

**Edit** :  It seems it was a dependancy issue. Adding "resize" to require on app.js has resolved it;

```
require(["resize","app/main"],function(){});
```

I thought suppling "resize" to define() in main.js would have ensured correct deps;

```
define([ 'require' , 'jquery' , ... ,'resize' ], function( require , $ , ... , resize )...
```

Comment: It seems it was a dependancy issue. see Edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was a dependancy issue.

Adding "resize" to require() within app.js has resolved it;

```
require(["resize","app/main"],function(){});
```

I thought suppling "resize" to define() in main.js would have ensured correct deps;

```
define([ 'require' , 'jquery' , ... ,'resize' ], function( require , $ , ... , resize )...
```